# How to find which entries will be updated during update

Tags: sql-server

I got a problem, my task is to find the places where user change data during update procedure. I have a form, which allows to edit information, and when is done, changes should be submitted to the database. At this point I suppose to do data compression.

How to find places where changes occur?

Is there any way to write SELECT which will find the entries which differ?

Comment: you have data compressed in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if this will help you out, but in MSSQL there are the following 2 Functions:

SoundEX & DIFFERENCE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx

You can look at the two differences of the compression or Data before compression, and see if they are similar.

Possibly.